# why does creating a local type vector fail

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    class Int {
        public:
            Int(int _i) : i(i) {}
        private:
            int i;
    };

    std::vector<Int> VI;
}
```

I try to compile the above code and got the following error message:

```
foo.cc: In function 'int main()':
foo.cc:13: error: 'main()::Int' uses local type 'main()::Int'
foo.cc:13: error:   trying to instantiate 'template<class _Alloc> class std::allocator'
foo.cc:13: error: template argument 2 is invalid
foo.cc:13: error: invalid type in declaration before ';' token
```

Could anyone of you tell me why I can't do things like this in C++? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not the same question, but another question on the same issue: [using local classes with stl algorithms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742607/using-local-classes-with-stl-algorithms)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The standard explictly prohibits using local classes to instantiate templates in 14.3.1[temp.arg.type]/2.

> A local type, a type with no linkage, an unnamed type or a type compounded from any of these types shall not be used as a template-argument for a template type-parameter.

This will be changed in C++0x.

Comment: I don't know about the reasons towards the decision in the past, but the fact that they have changed that limitation in C++0x seems to imply that the reasons were not so strong or needed to be overcome for other language features that were introduced --think lambdas, that actually create function objects in place.

Comment: AFAIK the old problem was with template instantiation. The compiler needs to decide whether `std::vector<Int>` is already instantiated, when it sees the definition of `VI`. That means it needs to be able to precisely identify _which_ definition of `Int` was used to instantiate that particular `std::vector<Int>`. You effectively need a unique mangled name for `Int`. In the example above, you could have something like `__main__Int`, but with nested unnamed scopes this is even harder.