# why this call operator has Compilation Error?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, operator-overloading

when compiling with mingw32-g++, there is error: no matching function for call to 'for_each(int [9], int*, main()::Output)', but can do well in vs2005?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {

  struct Output {
      void  operator () (int v) {
           std::cout << v << std::endl; 
       }
  };

  int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
  std::for_each(a, a + sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]), Output());

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @kain64b - I am not able to understand this code... can anyone describe a bit more on this...

Comment: it is  Call Operator overloaded

Comment: I'm kind of wondering why `main` is returning 1 after no apparent error.

Comment: chris,thanks  for your Carefulness!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In pre-C++11 version of the language types used as template arguments were required to have linkage. Local class declarations in C++ have no linkage, which is why they can't be used as template arguments in C++98/C++03. In those versions of the language you have to declare your class in namespace scope.

The linkage requirement was removed in C++11. Your code is valid from C++11 point of view. Apparently, you are compiling in pre-C++11 mode.

Comment: Unless you happen to have a C++11 conformat compiler (or one that doesn't know the rules - VS2005).

Comment: @Flexo: Why would it be a problem? Argument deduction mechanism will make `for_each` to receive its last argument *by value*. No problem whatsoever.

Answer (score 3):

You have to declare the `struct` outside of main. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742607/using-local-classes-with-stl-algorithms) for an explanation.