# "No matching function" for template function accepting a callback

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to pass a callback to a template function, but GCC gives me

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘Test::iterate(main(int, char**)::<anonymous struct>&)’
```

Why doesn't this work?
(Also, for reasons beyond my control, I can't use C++11.)

I've also tried naming the struct e.g. `myvis` and calling `test.iterate<myvis>(visitor)`, but that didn't work either.

```
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>

class Test {
public:
    std::deque<int> d;

    template <typename C>
    void iterate(C& c) {
        for(std::deque<int>::iterator itr = d.begin(); itr != d.end(); itr++) {
            c(*itr);
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Test test;
    test.d.push_back(1);
    test.d.push_back(2);
    struct {
        void operator()(int x) {
            std::cout << x << std::endl;
        }
    } visitor;
    test.iterate(visitor);
}
```

Comment: Try defining vistor globally. I think you have a scope issue

Comment: The answer can be found in [Using local classes with STL algorithms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742607/using-local-classes-with-stl-algorithms). The short version is that in C++03 you cannot use a local class in a template. If you define the visitor outside of `main`, as Charlie suggests, it will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C++03 standard says the following in §14.3.1.2 [temp.arg.type]:

> A local type, a type with no linkage, an unnamed type or a type
>   compounded from any of these types shall not be used as a
>   template-argument for a template type-parameter.

Therefore you need a global named struct instead of a local unnamed one, giving you something like the following:

```
struct Visitor {
    void operator()(int x) {
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }
} visitor;
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Test test;
    test.d.push_back(1);
    test.d.push_back(2);
    Visitor visitor;
    test.iterate(visitor);
}
```

The restrictions on local/unnamed typed have been lifted in c++11, so if those reasons not to use it go away someday your code will be fine as is.

Comment: ... and you have to name your struct.

Comment: I don't see why the restriction on local types was there, but I'm glad they lifted it in C++11.  Thanks!

Comment: … of course in C++11 you don’t need this convoluted workaround anymore anyway. ;-)

Comment: @KonradRudolph:... you don't even need to *name* the struct and go through the boilerplate code, just create a lambda.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Oh, sorry... I thought the *convoluted workaround* was having to move the type :)

Answer (score 1):

You have two errors.

First of all, you cannot use the local type `visitor` to instantiate the template member function function `iterate` (this would work in C++11).

Second, you cannot have an anonymous type here. You need a named `struct visitor` and you would need to pass an instance of that.

```
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>

struct visitor {
  void operator()(int x) {
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
  }
};

class Test {
public:
  std::deque<int> d;

  template <typename C>
  void iterate(C& c) {
    for(std::deque<int>::iterator itr = d.begin(); itr != d.end(); itr++) {
      c(*itr);
    }
  }
};

int main() {
  Test test;
  test.d.push_back(1);
  test.d.push_back(2);

  visitor v;
  test.iterate(v);
}
```

Comment: where did the OP try to pass in a temporary?

Comment: @Grizzly my bad, I am not used to the funny syntax.

Comment: visitor isn't a variable, it's a type.  I'm not using a temporary.

Comment: @AdamCrume you cannot pass a type to the `iterate` method. It needs a value.

Comment: @AdamCrume: As written in the question visitor is a variable.

Comment: @AdamCrume `struct { } someName;` is an instance of an anonymous struct.

Comment: Sorry, I got my comment backwards.  I meant that visitor in my code is a variable, not a type.

Answer (score 1):

You could make `visitor` global and you'll also need to name the `struct`, say something like `Visitor`.

```
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>

struct Visitor {
    void operator()(int x) 
    {
       std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }
};


class Test {
public:
    std::deque<int> d;

    template <typename C>
    void iterate(C& c) {
        for(std::deque<int>::iterator itr = d.begin(); itr != d.end(); itr++) {
            c(*itr);
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Test test;
    test.d.push_back(1);
    test.d.push_back(2);
    Visitor visitor;
    test.iterate(visitor);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to keep the variable local (unlike the struct which must be global)? Afterall unnecessary global variables are rarely a good idea for code simplicity and correctness.

Comment: @Grizzly  You are correct, keeping the variable `visitor` local could (and most of the time would) make more sense.  Edit made

Comment: I took the libery of actually declaring a local variable, since you seem to have missed that in your edit.