# Use a struct in a function outside of main

Tags: c++

To use a struct in a function outside of main(), can you use forward declaration and define it in main(), or does it have to be defined outside of a block?

Comment: Is there any specific advantage you're getting from defining it inside main when you're using it outside of main?

Comment: and, what happens if you try to do as you suggest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you define a structure inside of `main()`, it will hide the global name of the structure. So the function outside of `main()` will only be able to reference the global name. This example is taken from the C++ 2011 draft, Section 9.1 p2:

```
struct s { int a; };

void g() {
    struct s;              // hide global struct s
                           // with a block-scope declaration
    s* p;                  // refer to local struct s
    struct s { char* p; }; // define local struct s
    struct s;              // redeclaration, has no effect
}
```

There is no syntax to refer to the locally defined type from outside the function scope. <s>Because of that, even using a template will fail, because there is no way to express the instantiation of the template:</s>

```
template <typename F> void bar (F *f) { f->a = 0; }

int main () {
    struct Foo { int a; } f = { 3 };
    bar(&f);                         // fail in C++98/C++03 but ok in C++11
}
```

Actually, this is now allowed in C++11, as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/742617/315052).