# Is using a locally defined type in a template allowed?

Tags: c++

While [answering a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12487715/315052), I could not find a reason for why the following code would be disallowed.

```
template <typename F> void bar (F *f) { f->a = 0; }

int main () {
    struct Foo { int a; } f = { 3 };
    bar(&f);                         // fail
}
```

The explanation I provided was that the compiler would have no way to legally express the template expansion, but that is more my intuition than a reason. Is there a definitive explanation as to why the code should not compile?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: The problem was I was looking at the C++11 draft standard for a reason this was disallowed, and couldn't find it. However, I was using the compiler in it's default mode, not C++11 mode. The code does compile when I pass the C++11 switch to the compiler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is explicitly disallowed in C++03, but legal code in C++11.

Not sure if this is an exact duplicate of [Using local classes with STL algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742607/using-local-classes-with-stl-algorithms), as the standard has changed since I asked that question.