# class defined in function

Tags: c++, stl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using local classes with STL algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742607/using-local-classes-with-stl-algorithms)

I'm trying to pass a locally defined function object to STL functions and it does not work. Where in the world is it declared that this ought not to be possible ? That looks rather appealing to me !

Here's code that fails:

```
int main() {
  std::vector<int> v;
  struct gen { int operator()(){return 4;} };
  std::cout<<gen()()<<std::endl; // works
  std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(v),4,gen()); // fails
}
```

Incidentally, the following does work, not because gen_s is a struct, but because gen_s::gen is a static function. This is not so cool because what's the use of a stateless generator ?

```
std:vector<int> v;
struct gen_s { static int gen() { return 4; };
std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(v),5,gen_s::gen);
```

So, what about locally defined function objects ?

Comment: I think you meant `std::generate_n` instead of `std::generate` in the first piece of code.

Comment: Local classes as template parameters are allowed in C++11, but not in earlier versions.

Comment: @NPE Yes, I did a quick search with other keywords but didn't see this one. The answers it there.

Comment: By failing, I mean that it does not compile.