# Forward a template auto

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, type-traits

### Context

(1) One can extract the return type and the argument types of a callable with the following trait:

```
#include <tuple>

template<class T>
struct callable_trait
{};

template<class R, class... Args>
struct callable_trait<R(Args...)>
{
    using return_type    = R;
    using argument_types = std::tuple<Args...>;
};
```

(2) Since C++17, one can define a template with [`template<auto>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto):

> If a template parameter is declared `auto`, its type is deduced from the corresponding argument.

### Question

(3) I should then be able to provide some syntactic sugar:

```
template<auto callable>
using return_type = typename callable_trait<decltype(callable)>::return_type;
```

... but it doesn't work too well ...

```
void f();
void g(return_type<f>);
```

> ```
> error: no type named 'return_type' in 'callable_trait<void (*)()>'
> using return_type = typename callable_trait<decltype(callable)>::return_type;
> ^~~~~
> ```

A lambda doesn't help ...

```
auto lambda= [](){};
void h(return_type<lambda>);
```

> ```
> error: a non-type template parameter cannot have type '(lambda at <source>:19:14)'
> void h(return_type<lambda>);
>                    ^
> ```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/XTWgQ3)

**How can I circumvent this?**

Comment: Lambda doesn't work with non-type template parameter. As long as you want to use `auto`, you can't circumvent it. Free function, on the other hand, works if you add a partial specialization for function pointers, i.e. `struct callable_trait<R (*)(Args...)>`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the function case the issue here is that `decltype(callable)` for a function returns a function pointer, which doesn't match your specialization.  With the lambda, you get the type of the lambda, not it's `operator()`.  You'll have the same problem if you use a member function as well since your specialization doesn't match a member function pointer.

What you need is something that can take all of those types and give you an `R(Args...)` in return.  Thankfully we have `std::function` and it is built to do just this thing.  It has deduction guides that will allow it to take any function type and make a `std::function<R(Args...)>` to match its signature.  Using a `std::function` your code can become

```
template<class T>
struct callable_trait
{};

template<class R, class... Args>
struct callable_trait<std::function<R(Args...)>>
{
    using return_type    = R;
    using argument_types = std::tuple<Args...>;
    static constexpr size_t argument_count = sizeof...(Args);
};

template<auto callable>
using return_type = typename callable_trait<decltype(std::function{callable})>::return_type;

template<auto callable>
static constexpr size_t argument_count = callable_trait<decltype(std::function{callable})>::argument_count;

void f();
void g(return_type<f>);

auto lambda = [](){};
void h(return_type<lambda>);

void e(int, int, int);
static_assert(argument_count<e> == 3, "oh no");
```

but this only works on [gcc head](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZVk8xJD1kQiuIzlL).  Clang can't deduce the `std::function` and earlier versions of gcc and MSVS fail for the reason detailed here: [Why is gcc failing when using lambda for non-type template parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43213997/why-is-gcc-failing-when-using-lambda-for-non-type-template-parameter)

If you switch to taking a type parameter and use `decltype` is works on both gcc and MSVS but clang still has problems with the deduction guide

```
template<class T>
struct callable_trait
{};

template<class R, class... Args>
struct callable_trait<std::function<R(Args...)>>
{
    using return_type    = R;
    using argument_types = std::tuple<Args...>;
    static constexpr size_t argument_count = sizeof...(Args);
};

template<typename callable>
using return_type = typename callable_trait<decltype(std::function{std::declval<callable>()})>::return_type;

template<typename callable>
static constexpr size_t argument_count = callable_trait<decltype(std::function{std::declval<callable>()})>::argument_count;

void f();
void g(return_type<decltype(f)>);

auto lambda = [](){};
void h(return_type<decltype(lambda)>);

void e(int, int, int);
static_assert(argument_count<decltype(e)> == 3, "oh no");
```

Comment: nice explanation and elaburation!

Comment: I'm probably missing how this happens. `function` is a template class. I can't see how you'd be able to construct it without providing those arguments. When I try to do this I get: "error C2955: `std::function`: use of class template requires template argument list"

Comment: @jonathanmee C++17 gives us class template argument deduction so you don't have to specify the template parameters anymore.  std::function has a deduction guides that figures it out for us.  This is a really nice feature and I'm using it whenever I can.

Comment: Yeah I'm stuck on Visual Studio 15.6.7 which doesn't appear to support class template argument deduction T.T Is there any possibility of a generic workaround?

Comment: @JonathanMee I'm not aware of one.  You would have to specialize `callable_trait` for each type of callable (function pointers, functors, member function pointers).

Comment: @NathanOliverI Actually asked a question about it: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54990207/2642059 Seems like you're right :(