# Can I get the Return Type of a Function From a Signature?

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, return-type, decltype, result-of

So I have a ton of functions similar to these:

```
template <typename T>
bool Zero(const T, const T, const T);
template <typename T>
T One(const T, const T, const T, bool);
template <typename T>
T Three(const T, const T, const T, const T, const T, const T);
```

For each of these functions I have a wrapper which uses the return type of these functions so it looks something like this:

```
template <typename T>
decltype(Zero<decltype(declval<T>().x)>(decltype(declval<decltype(declval<T>().x)>()), decltype(declval<decltype(declval<T>().x)>()), decltype(declval<decltype(declval<T>().x)>()))) ZeroWrapper(const T);
template <typename T>
decltype(One<decltype(declval<T>().x)>(decltype(declval<decltype(declval<T>().x)>()), decltype(declval<decltype(declval<T>().x)>()), decltype(declval<decltype(declval<T>().x)>()), bool())) OneWrapper(const T);
template <typename T>
decltype(Three<decltype(declval<T>().x)>(decltype(declval<decltype(declval<T>().x)>()), decltype(declval<decltype(declval<T>().x)>()), decltype(declval<decltype(declval<T>().x)>()), decltype(declval<decltype(declval<T>().x)>()), decltype(declval<decltype(declval<T>().x)>()), decltype(declval<decltype(declval<T>().x)>()))) ThreeWrapper(const T);
```

As you can see all those `decltype(declval<T>().x)`'s get disgustingly hard to read. Can I template a `using` or is there some standard function which will allow me to extract the return type from a function pointer without passing the argument types to `decltype` or `result_of`? So something like this:

```
template <typename T>
foo_t<Zero<decltype(declval<T>().x)>> ZeroWrapper(const T);
template <typename T>
foo_t<One<decltype(declval<T>().x)>> OneWrapper(const T);
template <typename T>
foo_t<Three<decltype(declval<T>().x)>> ThreeWrapper(const T);
```

Comment: Does it help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54827950/5470596?

Comment: `decltype(declval<decltype(declval<T>().x)>())` seems like a noop. Why not just type alias it to something and reduce boilerplate?

Comment: Live demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ecdbe6b6260cb7c0 ;)

Comment: @YSC it looks like they call functions with `.x` field in the wrapper in the question's example.

Comment: Also, have you tried just using `auto` type deduction? Or trailing return type `auto ZeroWrapper(const T arg) -> decltype(Zero(arg.x));`?

Comment: @DanM. I'm not sure it really matters... _"Can I template a using or is there some standard function which will allow me to extract the return type from a function pointer without passing the argument types to decltype or result_of?"_

Comment: I'll answer properly and let the score system decide ^^

Comment: `Zero<decltype(declval<T>().x)>` - Do you expect `T` to be a reference type (can only happen if explicitly provided)? And intend to support the case? If not, then `declval<T>().x` here can be substituted for the more readable `T::x`

Comment: @DanM. I haven't tried type deduction... Honestly I know it's a thing... I'm just not familiar with how to use it.

Comment: @JonathanMee in many cases you can just use `auto` as a return type and if your function is simple enough it'll just work.

Comment: @DanM. Unfortunately these are toy wrapper functions. My real wrapper functions need a return type for more metaprogramming as part of an `enable_if` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) the [`function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) object has been endowed with a [Deduction Guide](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/deduction_guides) which allows it to determine it's type from the argument passed to the constructor. So for example, given the function `int foo()` in [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) we had to do:

```
function<int()> bar(foo);
```

In [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) `bar`'s `function<int()>` type will be derived if we simply:

```
function bar(foo);
```

Thus we can use the Deduction Guide to populate a temporary `function` with *only* the signature; thereby using `function`'s `result_type` to find the result of your helper funcitons:

```
template <typename T>
typename decltype(function(Zero<decltype(declval<T>().x)>))::return_type ZeroWrapper(const T);
template <typename T>
typename decltype(function(One<decltype(declval<T>().x)>))::return_type OneWrapper(const T);
template <typename T>
typename decltype(function(Three<decltype(declval<T>().x)>))::return_type ThreeWrapper(const T);
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4f559e71383f7c9f)

Comment: It's worth noting that while this does solve the problem for C++17 compilers, this does not solve it for Visual Studio 15.6.7 which I'm stuck using, as it's not C++17 compliant a fact that may be obvious since I'm asking about `result_of` and not `invoke_result`.

Comment: I've found a potential workaround here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54990207/2642059 Which works on C++14... but sadly *still* doesn't work on Visual Studio 15.6.7: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55047417/2642059

Comment: Final update, I did identify a C++14/Visual Studio 15.6.7 solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55050902/2642059

Answer (score 1):

> Can I template a using or is there some standard function which will allow me to extract the return type from a function pointer without passing the argument types to `decltype` or `result_of`?

Yes!

```
#include <tuple>
#include <functional>

template<class T>
struct callable_trait
{};

template<class R, class... Args>
struct callable_trait<std::function<R(Args...)>>
{
    using return_type    = R;
    using argument_types = std::tuple<Args...>;
};

template<auto callable>
using return_type = typename callable_trait<decltype(std::function{callable})>::return_type;
```

`return_type<some_callable>` is the type returned by `some_callable` when called with appropriate arguments. This uses a `std::function` in order to provide a specialization for each possible kind of callable (free function, function pointer, member function, functor object). This is [explained in this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54828930/5470596).

---

In your case, you can use it like so:

```
template <typename T>
bool Zero(const T, const T, const T);
template <typename T>
T One(const T, const T, const T, bool);
template <typename T>
T Three(const T, const T, const T, const T, const T, const T);

template <typename T>
return_type<Zero<T>>  ZeroWrapper(const T);
template <typename T>
return_type<One<T>>   OneWrapper(const T);
template <typename T>
return_type<Three<T>> ThreeWrapper(const T);
```

[Full demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ecdbe6b6260cb7c0)

Comment: This works like a charm... mostly... I'm on trapped on an older version of Visual Studio 2017 which doesn't support `auto` template parameters. I'm trying to hack around this without having to pass two template parameters to `return_type`... If you have any suggestions...

Comment: Yeah, that looks like it should have worked but I'm getting the error: "error C2955: `std::function`: use of class template requires template argument list"