# Can I generate a function without providing arguments?

Tags: c++, function, c++14, c++17, template-argument-deduction

So [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) has [`std::function` Deduction Guides](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/deduction_guides) so given:

```
int foo();
```

I can do:

```
std::function bar(foo);
```

But I'm stuck on a [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) compiler. There I have to do something more like: `function<int()> bar(foo)`. I was wondering if there was a way to create a `std::function` without passing the function pointer *and* explicitly providing the function signature? So for example [`make_pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair) will deduce the type of it's return from it's arguments. I was wondering if I could write something similar for `function`s even using [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14), like:

```
auto bar = make_function(foo);
```

Is this doable?

<sub>Note: My real case is that `foo` is a template function with a lot of arguments I don't want to deduce. So my motivation here is to generate a `function` *without* needing to provide the parameter types.</sub>

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bf40854ec289911d)

Comment: In your real case, `std::function bar(foo)` doesn't work in [tag:c++17].  Please provide an actual [MCVE] of what you want to do in legal [tag:c++17], and ask for something similar to be implemented in [tag:c++14].

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I'm not certain what you mean about it not working... I've added an example though :shrug:

Comment: **"My real case is that foo is a template function with a lot of arguments"** -- your "[MCVE]" is fundamentally different than your real use case, [as your real use case doesn't work here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f7be1b22acff917).  When writing a [MCVE], start with a *real use case*, then minimize.  Don't minimize *first*.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont So [this is my original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54984669/2642059). You can see my answer at the bottom. My point in the comment was to ask for a way to generate a `function` which could be fully defined by my passing just a function pointer. I thought that was clear? Is my edit working for you?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I'm going to take it from your edit that you are affirming where we're at with this now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question has some most important part in the end in the fine print. If your `foo` is a template, C++17 deduction guides won't help you with a simple syntax like

```
std::function f(foo);
```

You'd still need to provide template arguments for `foo`. Assuming you are OK with specifying `foo`'s argument types (as you have to be) writing make_func is a trivial exercise:

```
 template<class R, class... ARGS>
 auto make_func(R (*ptr)(ARGS...)) {
      return std::function<R (*)(ARGS...)>(ptr);
 }
```

And than you use it:

```
auto bar = make_func(&foo<Z, Y, Z>);
```

Comment: I'm accepting because this is a genius solution on C++14. But I'm annoyed to say that this still doesn't work on Visual Studio 2017 version 15.6.7: ideone.com/T52Gxn I get this error: "error C2039: `result_type`: is not a member of global namespace" when I try to use `make_func` to obtain the return type in an `enable_if_t`. I'm going to open a new question to see if there is a workaround...

Comment: I've asked my follow up here if you have any suggestions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55047417/2642059

Comment: Just a note to any future readers, I needed a function to return a `std::funciton` so I could extract the return type. This is a fantastic answer, and should be accepted for the given question. However if your interests align more closely with mine I've based a C++14 answer off this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55050902/2642059