# Templates, inner structs, local types, and pure virtual functions, oh my

Tags: templates, c++11, g++, pure-virtual

Consider an example where a method is pure virtual, takes a parameter of a templated type (injected from an outer type), and that templated type is a local type (defined in a function body). This scenario causes a compile-time error under g++. Admittedly, this is quite a corner case, but it does originate from real code. Here's a compilable, reproducible example:

```
#include <cstdio>

template<typename T>
struct Outer
{
    struct InnerBase
    {
        virtual void foo(T const&) = 0;
        virtual void bar(T const&) {  };
    };

    struct InnerDerived : public InnerBase
    {
        void foo(T const&) override { std::printf("virtual call foo() worked\n"); }
        void bar(T const&) override { std::printf("virtual call bar() worked\n"); }
    };

    InnerBase* inner;
    Outer() : inner(new InnerDerived()) {  }
};


struct NonLocalStruct { };

int main()
{
    struct LocalStruct { };

    Outer<NonLocalStruct> a;
    Outer<LocalStruct>    b;

    a.inner->foo(NonLocalStruct());     // fine
    a.inner->bar(NonLocalStruct());     // fine
    b.inner->foo(LocalStruct());        // causes error
    b.inner->bar(LocalStruct());        // fine

    return 0;
}
```

Can someone explain why this causes a compile error? Why does it work with non-local types but not local ones? Why do non-pure virtual methods work but not pure ones?

I'm using g++ 4.8.1 with -std=c++11 (I've also tried this example in VS2010 and it compiles and runs without errors).

The exact error from g++ is:

> test.cpp:8:16: error: 'void Outer::InnerBase::foo(const T&) [with T = main()::LocalStruct]', declared using local type 'const main()::LocalStruct', is used but never defined [-fpermissive]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using local classes with STL algorithms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742607/using-local-classes-with-stl-algorithms)

Comment: @John: I don't think that question is a duplicate, since it only applies to C++98/03, not C++11 (where local types can be template parameters). Also, it doesn't explain the pure vs. non-pure virtual behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that this is a g++ bug, that is somehow related to an old C++98 restriction on the use of local classes as template parameters

> // C++98 Standard
>
> **14.3.1/2**: A local type, a type with no linkage, an unnamed type or a type compounded from any of these types shall not be used as a
> template-argument for a template type-parameter.

In C++11, this restriction has been lifted. As you note, Visual Studio compiles this correctly, and so does Clang. As a work-around, adding the definition of the abstract function works with g++

```
template<typename T>
void Outer<T>::InnerBase::foo(T const&) {};
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a340548561f8829c).

I think you should submit a [**bug report**](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/) to g++.

Comment: Turns out it's [already been reported](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51048)! Thanks.