# What is the "best" way to initialize a C++ vector?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

My question is for the C++ purists here. I know that Bjarne Stroustrop wants us to get in the habit of using C++ vectors: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQs6IC-vgmo

For C-style arrays you do:

```
int arr[] = {69, 2, 3};
```

What is the equivalent way to initialize a C++ vector? That is, when you're programming in C++ and need a dynamic, random-access container and you already know some of the elements that need to be in it, what is the best way to initialize that sucker?

Obviously you can do

```
int myints[] = {16,2,77,29};
std::vector<int> fifth (myints, myints + sizeof(myints) / sizeof(int) )
```

but that's not very elegant ....

Comment: Are you OK with C++11? If yes, do `std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4};` :)

Comment: As of C++11, same as arrays. Else, create your own versions of `std::begin` and `std::end`.

Answer (score 5):

C++11 syntax:

```
vector<int> arr = {69, 2, 3};
```

That's all.

The curly braces initalizer produces a `std::initializer_list<int>`, which is then passed to a `std::vector` constructor.

Comment: @ Cheers and hth: Is this any better or worse? `vector<int> arr{69,2,3};`

Comment: @DavidO: Define "better", and there you have your answer. However, i prefer the `=`, where it's possible. I had to check whether `arr{69, 2}` produced a 2-item vector or invoking the repeat-constructor producing 69 items; happily it created a 2-item vector...

Comment: @DavidO It'd be required if the constructor in question was `explicit`. Otherwise it's a matter of preference.

Answer (score 2):

If it's C++03 you're after, then use vector's iterating constructor (as you did); perhaps you can make it "look" more elegant by moving the array length into a header (macro).

```
// in some header
template <typename T, size_t N>
const char (&arr_len(const T (&arr) [N]))[N];
#define ARRAY_LEN(arr) sizeof(arr_len(arr))

// in your source
int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
std::vector v(arr, arr + ARRAY_LEN(arr));
```

---

If it's C++11 like I posted in the comment, use the vector's initializer list taking constructor.

```
std::vector v{ 1, 2, 3, 4};
```

However, efficiency-wise I don't see why one would be better than the other.

Comment: @Koushik: Only if you're allowed to use C++11, the first part works in pure C++03. `array_len` returns the size of array at compile-time.

Comment: it would be nice with uppercase for the macro. worth noting that in C++03 (which it's meant for) it doesn't work for array of local type. however, we usually didn't mind. the nice thing about this approach is that it produces a compile time constant, which can be used to specify the size of another array.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Made the macro uppercase. Why _it doesn't work for array of local type_?

Comment: @legends2k: because in C++03 templates couldn't be instantiated on local types. as i recall because they had no linkage. however, in c++11 still no linkage (as far as I'm aware), but template instantion allowed. i would have to look up the details to be sure of the reasons though.

Comment: Got it, thanks! Adding [the relevant post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/742607/183120) for others.

Comment: while we're on it, the sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a) thing can also produce a compile time constant and be wrapped in a macro, but afaik only with run-time (dynamic) type checking... so it's mostly inferior. only relevant as an alternative for arrays of local types, in c++03.

Comment: But isn't `sizeof` evaluated at compile-time (except for C's VLAs)?

Comment: @legends2k: not sure what you mean. in c++ `sizeof` is very much compile time. in C its broken for VLAs by not being compile time for them. that will not be repeated for VLAs in C++14. if they eppear in C++14.

Comment: I was asking regarding the `sizeof` solution to get the array size, where you'd mentioned it'll work only with run-time type checking.

Comment: @legends2k: oh. the problem is when `a`, inadvertently, is a pointer. the runtime checking can be done by dereferencing and taking address, use `typeid` to check if you still have the same type, put that in an `assert`(say) and put that again inside a comma expression. very awkward! but perhaps better than nothing.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf VLA's are coming to c++14? is it that std::dynarray thingy or c-like VLA?