# C++11 Local static values not working as template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I can't seem to use local static values as template arguments, in C++11. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <const char* Str>
void print() {
  cout << Str << endl;
}

int main() {
  static constexpr char myStr[] = "Hello";
  print<myStr>();
  return 0;
}
```

In GCC 4.9.0, the code errors with

```
error: ‘myStr’ is not a valid template argument of type ‘const char*’ because ‘myStr’ has no linkage
```

In Clang 3.4.1, the code errors with

```
candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'Str'
```

Both compilers were run with -std=c++11

A link to an online compiler where you can select one of many C++ compilers: http://goo.gl/a2IU3L

Note, moving `myStr` outside `main` compiles and runs as expected.

Note, I have looked at similar StackOverflow questions from before C++11, and most indicate that this should be resolved in C++11. For example [Using local classes with STL algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742607/using-local-classes-with-stl-algorithms)

Comment: I think [EWG issue 155/N4198](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4198.html) explains this very well, in particular *"the restriction to entities with linkage is an artifact of exported templates, and could have been removed when the linkage restrictions on template type parameters were removed"*

Comment: As far as I can make out, a variable declared at block scope (in this case function variable) has no linkage unless declared `extern`, in which case is has external linkage. I'm not sure there is a way to declare block scope variable with internal linkage.

Comment: @PiotrS. I can't tell which version of C++ [EWG issue 155/N4198] is referring to. Is it for C++11?

Comment: It's a paper dated 2014-10-06; it is a proposal for future language evolution and concerns the restrictions imposed on the language by the most recent C++ standard. In other words, as of now your `myStr` is an address of an object with *no linkage* (although it has a static storage duration) hence not allowed as a non-type template argument by the standard. It is proposed to remove the "linkage" constraint, so that an address of the object with static storage duration will be a constant expression allowed as a non-type template argument.

Comment: [Apparently](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/tCtT4e) your code example is compiled by newer compilers (gcc 7.2 or newer) and newer language dialect (C++17 or newer).

Answer (score 3):

Apparently "no linkage" means ["The name can be referred to only from the scope it is in."](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Linkage) including local variables. Those aren't valid in template parameters because their address isn't known at compile time apparently.

Easy solution is to make it a global variable. It doesn't really change your code.

See also https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52036

Comment: The code above is simplified from the original context. In my actual code, I have a macro that creates both lines: the const string and the function call. The macro cannot create a global variable and a local function call.

Comment: Regarding the gcc bug, any idea why clang would fail in the same way?

Comment: @user108088 Same bug in clang?

Comment: @user108088. I think this gcc bug is the `static` vs. `extern`. Clang accepts the internal vs. external linkage, gcc sees the `static` has having no linkage. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d93fe317886484d

Comment: @BЈовић If this is a bug in gcc, than I would expect another, independently produced, compiler would be unlikely to have the same bug. Clang doesn't compile the code either.