# Enum local to a function in C++03

Tags: c++, c++03

Why is the following snippet not legal in C++03?

```
template <typename T>
void poison(T& x) {}

int main() {
    enum Enum { A, B, C };
    Enum e = A;
    poison(e);
    return 0;
}
```

gcc 5.4 compiler output in C++03 mode: https://godbolt.org/g/6hKc7F

If I move `Enum` outside `main()`, it compiles fine in C++03 mode. Alternatively, if I enable C++11, it compiles fine as well.

How did scoping rules change between C++03 and C++11 such that this code is now valid?

Comment: Template cannot take local type in C++03. C++11 allows that (so we can use lambda).

Comment: Thanks @Jarod42, that's the wording I was missing for proper googling. Relevant post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/742617/393756